# strftime returns ValueError

Tags: python, datetime

strftime returns Value error. Why?

This is the code

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%-m')
```

My output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Comment: did you import datetime ?

Comment: Yes. All are working expect this one. I need to convert month to Integer

Comment: it works fine, what's you os ?

Comment: if you need negative value then you have to put `-` before `%` like `"-%m"`

Comment: based on [strftime.org](https://strftime.org/) format can depend on system. On Unix it needs `-` but on Windows it may need `#` like `%#m`. I could test it only on LInux and both works for me - `"%-m %#m"`

Comment: @MaharshiBingumalla ***"I need to convert month to Integer"***: `.month` is allready of type `int`, do `print(datetime.datetime.now().month)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [strftime.org](https://strftime.org) format can depend on system.

On Unix it may needs `-` like `"%-m"` but on Windows it may need `#` like `"%#m"`.

I could test it only on Linux and both works for me: `"%-m %#m"`

---

**BTW:** but if you want to get negative value then you need `-` before `%` like `"-%m"`